# VS2013 Form: How can I disable style change on mouseover?

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2013, styles

Visual Studio has a mandatory(?) style property 'mouseOverBackColor' that insists on changing the style of a button/checkbox. I would like the button to retain it's current style and ignore mouseEnter/Over/Leave events.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **FormNameDesigner.cs**, you can prevent to activate events that which ignore you want. Before you should select events and create method in **buttonName.Properties** window. For button,

```
this.button1.MouseEnter -= new 
System.EventHandler(this.button1_MouseEnter);
this.button1.MouseLeave -= new
System.EventHandler(this.button1_MouseLeave);
this.button1.MouseHover -= new
System.EventHandler(this.button1_MouseHover);
```